# Why is this CMDeviceMotionHandler never called by CoreMotion?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-motion

I've included the CoreMotion framework in my project and imported the CoreMotion framework in the header of my view controller:

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

Then in -viewDidLoad I have this simple test code which I run on an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    [motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:0.1];

    CMDeviceMotionHandler  motionHandler = ^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"foo");

    };

    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:motionHandler];

    NSLog(@"merde!");
}
```

When I run the project on the device and move it around, I never get a "foo" log. Also, I tried setting a breakpoint in the motion handler block and it never halts there. But I do get the "merde!" log, so this code is definitely executed.

Why is core motion not calling my handler? My iPhone 4 is functional. Accelerometers and gyro work perfectly in other apps. There is no hardware bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had very similar code running successfully, same applies to the available samples in the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW22) (there is only an appropriate one for gyro data). But there is one major difference:

All implementations hold their own reference to the opereation queue with `operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] retain];` or build their own. So hopefully this helps to get more than 'merde' in your logs ;-)